# gem wicked routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good day!.
I'm implementing a wicked gem... and get a routing error.

```
no route matches [POST] "/user_signup/address"
```

Although my routes

```
  resources :users
  resources :user_signup
```

controller

```
 class UserSignupController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps  :address, :company_info, :sum_up
```

And when i try to submit a form for address:

```
p address
= form_for @user, url: wizard_path do |f|
  p
    = f.label :address
    = f.text_field :address
  p
   = f.submit 'Continue'
= link_to 'Skip', next_wizard_path
```

i get this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me. changed to

```
= form_for @user, url: wizard_path, :method => :put do |f|
```

`method: :put` didn't work, and it's ok!